# using Swiping Gestures from top to bottom control the volume in android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to control the volume using swiping gestures, if i swipe on the screen from top to bottom, it should reduce and i swipe from bottom to top, it should increase the volume. Instead of using volume buttons.

Comment: First check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so what do you have problems with? what have you already done?

Comment: Set a touch listener on the layout and interpret the movements. **Please post some code(Show us what you have tried), so that other people can help you** and please check the link @MaciejBiałorucki before posting questoins

Comment: You know how to set listner or volume ?

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    enum Direction{
        LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN;
    }

    private final static String TAG = "ClickFrame";
    private final static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;

    // 0: uninitialized
    // 1: horizontal
    // 2: vertical
    private int initialGesture;

    protected float initialX;
    protected float initialY;
    private float decidedX;
    private float decidedY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = event.getX();
                initialY = event.getY();
                initialGesture = 0;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float deltaX;
                float deltaY;
                if(initialGesture == 0) {
                    deltaX = event.getX() - initialX;
                    deltaY = event.getY() - initialY;
                }
                else{
                    deltaX = event.getX() - decidedX;
                    deltaY = event.getY() - decidedY;
                }

                if(initialGesture == 0 && Math.abs(deltaX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD){
                    initialGesture = 1;
                    decidedX = event.getX();
                    decidedY = event.getY();
                    if(deltaX > 0){
                        onBeforeMove(Direction.RIGHT);
                    }
                    else{
                        onBeforeMove(Direction.LEFT);
                    }
                }
                else if(initialGesture == 0 && Math.abs(deltaY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD){
                    initialGesture = 2;
                    decidedX = event.getX();
                    decidedY = event.getY();
                    if(deltaY > 0){
                        onBeforeMove(Direction.DOWN);
                    }
                    else{
                        onBeforeMove(Direction.UP);
                    }
                }

                if(initialGesture == 1){
                    if(deltaX > 0){
                        onMove(Direction.RIGHT, deltaX);
                    }
                    else{
                        onMove(Direction.LEFT, -deltaX);
                    }
                }
                else if(initialGesture == 2){
                    if(deltaY > 0){
                        onMove(Direction.DOWN, deltaY);
                    }
                    else{
                        onMove(Direction.UP, -deltaY);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                deltaX = event.getX() - initialX;
                deltaY = event.getY() - initialY;

                if(initialGesture == 0){
                    onClick();
                    return true;
                }
                onAfterMove();
                initialGesture = 0;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public abstract void onMove(Direction dir, float diff);

    public abstract void onClick();

    public abstract void onAfterMove();

    public abstract void onBeforeMove(Direction dir);
}
```

then 
mClickFrame.setOnTouchListener(clickFrameSwipeListener);

Comment: all of above can be done in just few lines of code using `GestureDetector`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @pskink the right method is to use `GestureDetector` (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection) and implement pan/panStop on a GestureListener to detect the entry location and exit location.